# How to evaluate custom parenthesis expression in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, algorithm, validation

I am working on parentheses position validation in a string expression using C#. The expression looks like below.

```
"Loan no = 12345 AND Borrower First Name Contains Milena OR Buy Side Lock Date = 03/13/2016 AND Last Finished Milestone = Decisioned OR Subject Property State = NC AND Loan Amt > 50000"
```

Here 'AND' and 'OR' are the two different operations that can be performed between two conditions. We have API in C# to evaluate two conditions containing an operation.

With these things in place, the end users are allowed to place the parentheses from UI between two or more conditions in order to evaluate those conditions on priority basis. However UI allows them to put parentheses only at the beginning or end of a condition.

Let's say in the above example, if the user want to evaluate the second and third condition on priority basis he/she put the parentheses between them as shown below.

```
Loan no = 12345 AND (Borrower First Name Contains Milena OR Buy Side Lock Date = 03/13/2016) AND Last Finished Milestone = Decisioned OR Subject Property State = NC AND Loan Amt > 50000.
```

However the end user can put as many parentheses as he/she wants. Now in the above expression with parentheses in place between second and third conditions if the user tries to put the parentheses between first and second conditions the logic breaks as the second and third conditions are already in parentheses which needs to be evaluated first. In this case I want to prevent the user from putting the parentheses between first and second conditions.

I checked few articles in the net which helps me in identifying the number of left parentheses count are equal to number of right parentheses count. However that will not help me in identifying the above problem.

Does any one has any suggestions?

Comment: Without your code, I am afraid only you can solve this.

Comment: Your narrative is a little unclear, but is your concern to ensure that parentheses are correctly *nested*? Also, what is the nature of your `Condition` values? Could they e.g. contain some form of strings themselves, where parentheses within such strings don't count as real parentheses? If so, you may be better off looking towards an actual parser rather than thinking about regex.

Comment: *"(...) if there is already a parentheses between Condition2 and Condition4 I want to stop the user from putting the parentheses between Condition1 and Condition3 (...)"*. Why would `(Condition1 AND (Condition2 OR Condition3) AND Condition4) OR Condition5 AND Condition6` be invalid? There is no syntax error in the expression. There might be a logic "error" according to some rules you haven't told us but that is a whole other ballpark.

Comment: @InBetween, Yes, by syntax it is not wrong. However to execute my business logic I want to put this validation in place. I have updated my question with how a condition look like. The innermost expression has to be evaluated first. Hence the position of the parentheses matters for me.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have updated the question to show how a condition look like in C# string expression. And I am sure that these condition won't involve parentheses in themselves.

Comment: What *exactly* is it about `(Condition1 AND (Condition2 OR Condition3) AND Condition4)` that's incorrect? You said "they can be nested"; well, those *are* nested. So what exactly about that nesting is not to be allowed? Is your validation then that all nestings share an endpoint? Or are you tracking all changes to the string expression, and taking its history into consideration?

Comment: Or to take your messages even more literally, are you requiring that all nestings share the first endpoint? Would `((C1 AND C2) OR (C3 AND C4))` be allowed?

Comment: So you're trying to prevent the user from turning `x = A and (B or C)` into `x=(A and (B) or C)`? (I just added the left paren in front of `A` and the right paren after `B`.) That's a valid expression, so you can't kill it for syntactic reasons. You'll need a parse tree of the existing expression so that you can detect when the user's actions will cross expressions like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply checking if parenthesis nesting is correct then you can do the following:

```
public static bool ParenthesisAreValid(this string str)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         return true;

     var openParenthesis = 0;

     foreach (var c in str)
     {
         if (c == '(')
         {
             openParenthesis++;
         }
         else if (c == ')')
         {
             openParenthesis--;
         }

         if (openParenthesis < 0)
            return false;
     }

     return openParenthesis == 0;
}
```

What this does is simply scan the whole string keeping track of how many open parenthesis expressions it has encountered so far. Each open parenthesis increments the count and every close parenthesis decrements it. If the count ever reaches `-1` then we have a close parenthesis mismatch and the expression is not valid. Also, if once we've finished parsing the string the parenthesis count is not equal to zero then we have missing close parenthesis and the expression isn't valid either.

If you simply want to disallow nested parenthesis (or as you put it, intercepting expressions) then also return `false` whenever `openParenthesis > 1`.

```
if (openParenthesis < 0 || openParenthesis > 1)
    return false;
```

Note that this does not check other syntactic rules which are not included in your question and you probably might need to consider; the following expression would be flagged as valid and it's obviously wrong:

```
Condition1 (AND Condition2 OR) Condition3 AND Condition4 OR Condition5 AND Condition6
```

Comment: I don't want to disallow nested parentheses. Nested parentheses can be there. However I don't want the user to intercept the existing parentheses explained above with the example of 'Condition'. For example, below one is a valid expression. (((C1 AND C2) OR C3) AND C4). Here though the expression is nested none of the conditions are intercepted. C1 and C2 evaluated first then the out put of this is evaluated with C3 and this output is evaluated with C4.

Comment: @user3796454 the way you phrased that makes me wonder: are you aware that nestings like `(C1 AND (C2 OR C3) AND C4)` are evaluated just as simply as `(((C1 AND C2) OR C3) AND C4)`? Just evaluate `(C2 OR C3)` first, and then evaluate that result with `C1` and `C4`.